# Relation between C-groups and reflection groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, gt.geometric-topology, coxeter-groups, reflection-groups, abstract-polytopes

Take a set of reflections $\{r_1,\ldots,r_k\}$ of $\mathbb R^n$. Sometimes, the group presentation will turn out to be a C-group – this is where the regular planar polytopes in Euclidean space, including the star polytopes, come from.

I'm looking for necessary and sufficient conditions for these reflections to create a C-group. I don't really have any ideas as to how I'd find something like this. I've scoured the literature to no success.

At the very least, I conjecture that if the normal vectors of the reflections are linearly independent, the group should be a C-group. This isn't a necessary condition though, as shown by the affine Coxeter groups.

**Note 1:** Just in case it wasn't clear, I'm talking about C-groups, i.e. groups with a distinguished generating set $\langle \rho_1,\ldots,\rho_n\rangle$ where all generators are involutions, satisfying the intersection condition $$\langle \rho_i : i\in I\rangle\cap \langle \rho_j : j\in J\rangle = \langle \rho_i : i\in I\cap J\rangle.$$
These aren't the same as Coxeter groups, though they're related. Any Coxeter group is a C-group, and every C-group is a quotient of a Coxeter group (though the converse isn’t always true). Every regular abstract polytope defines a C-group (its automorphism group), and viceversa. For a complete exposition, see Abstract Regular Polytopes by McMullen and Schulte, pp. 49-60.

**Note 2:** I'm aware of the result by Coxeter that any discrete reflection group admits a Coxeter group presentation (and in particular a C-group presentation), but that's not what I'm talking about here. Here, I'm fixing the presentation so that it specifically uses the given reflections.

Comment: Perhaps it's worth commenting that the notion of "C-group" is not widely known -- I'd never heard of it before, for instance. By contrast, Coxeter groups are of course widely studied. Perhaps a more focused question about their relationship would provoke some answers. At the very least, it would help if you expanded on your assertion that "These aren't the same as Coxeter groups, though they're related". How are they related? Why are they different?

Comment: Another small comment. You say that C-groups are defined by "group presentations $\langle \rho_1,\ldots,\rho_n\rangle$ where all generators are involutions" but this isn't a presentation, just  a generating set. Giving the actual definition would make the question more accessible.

Comment: I added some extra info about C-groups, and fixed the definition.

Comment: Thanks! The definition is now clear. I still think a more focused question is likely to get better answers, though.